# Run File option greyed out whenever I make a new class in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question since I'm a beginner, but I have this problem whenever I create a new class file, I can't seem to run it. The Run File option is always greyed out, along with Debug File and Profile File. And when I use the Run button at the top, I'm stuck with the text "Initializing view, please wait ..." I can't delete the file as well. I also noticed that its icon is different from other ones. I don't know if this is related but the Navigator is also stuck on "Please Wait..." I didn't have this problem before but since fresh installing my OS, I've had it. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVzFM.png)
Help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: Another thing I noticed is that corrections/error messages (the red/yellow underlines & the lightbulbs) won't show up in my Netbeans even if I intentionally make the codes wrong. Also noticed that if I change the codes in my previous java files (the ones I created before reinstalling my OS) and I run it, the output is the same as before the change (EDIT: Somehow fixed this by deleting the .class file through Windows Explorer). So I'm thinking this may be an issue with the IDE, since in other software like VSCode I was able to run the file. But still if anyone can fix this issue I would greatly appreciate it. This is the codes for one of the files I'm not able to run.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class TwoDArray {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //declaration of Array A
   int a[][] = new int [3][3];
 
   //take input into array a
   System.out.println(" Enter Values in Array A");

   for(int row=0;row<3;row++){    // count the number of rows

      for(int col=0;col<3;col++){   // count the number of columns

         System.out.println("Enter a value to Array a[" +row +"]["+col+"]:");
         a[row][col]=input.nextInt();

      }//end of inner for -j 

   System.out.println();//new line  

   }  // end of outer for - i

   System.out.println(" Values in Array a");

   for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
      
      for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
         System.out.print(a[row][col]+" ");
      } // inner for
   
   System.out.println();//new line

   }  // outer for

   } // end of method

} // end of class
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Sorry if this is late but I already posted it.

Comment: [1] Your code does not have a `package` statement as its first line. That is not strictly essential, but it is a very strong Java convention, and I'm guessing that you inadvertently deleted it. [2] Assuming that you specified a package when the project was created, add a `package` statement at the very start of your code. For example, if your package was `twodarray`, make `package twodarray;` the first line of your code, before the `import`. I tried that, and then your code ran just fine. [3] If that doesn't work then update your question with full details of how you created the project.

Comment: Turns out that the IDE itself was the problem. I reinstalled it and now it's working just fine. But I'll keep in mind about the package statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you create a new class it is basically empty.
For 'Run File' and other options to become active, you must at least supply a main method:

```
public class Myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

As soon as you have that method Java can use it as an entry point.

Comment: The class does have a main method yet I still can't run it.